# How can black mate white in 4 moves in this game

Tags: checkmate

How can black mate in 4 moves?

```
[FEN "6k1/p5rp/3p1PR1/3Pp2Q/qBK1Pp2/5P2/2P5/r5R1 b - - 0 1"]
[Event "Black to mate in 4 moves"]
```

Comment: Is White moving up the board as usual, or have you posted the diagram upside down?

Comment: @bof the file letters and rank numbers are *just* visible - we are looking from Black POV

Answer (score 4):

This does not seem too difficult.

> Due to the threats against the black king, black is basically forced to check at each move. Also, obviously you don't want to allow the white king to escape via c3 or d3 towards e2 or d2 where it would be relatively save.

With this in mind, the solution comes almost naturally:

> 1... Qxc2+ 2. Bc3 (2. Kb5 Qe2+ (or Qd3+) 3. Kc6 Ra6++ (or Qa6++)) Qe2+ 3. Kb4 (3. Kb3 Qa2+ 4. Kb4 Qa4++) a5+ 4. Kb3 Qa2++ One thing you need to check is that the more natural 1... Qxc2+ 2. Bc3 Ra4+ does not lead to mate in 4 (but only to mate in 5)

Comment: The tricky part is knowing to look for the mate.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Agreed, but since you don't want to let the white king escape towards c3/d3 and since you are forced to check with each move there are not all that many options. 2...Ra4+ would probably be more natural, but leads to a mate in 5, not 4 moves.

Comment: It was easy but I couldn't see it

Comment: @Rafiq I only saw it because I was told it was there.